# Knockout JS Observable Array and Model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am trying to learn how to use knockout and have yet to find a simple example for what i am trying to achieve. I am simply wanting to bind a List inside of my mvc Model class to my viewModel for knockout. For instance if i have the model below..this is one class file.

```
public class PropaneMaintModel
{
   public List<PropaneMaintAssignment> PropaneMaint{get;set;}
   public List<string> LocationIds { get; set; }
   public int? SelectedLocation { get; set; }
}

public class PropaneMaintAssignment
{
    public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public int Tanks { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Tank Size must have a value")]
    [Range(0,10000,ErrorMessage="Tank Size must be between 0 and 10000.")]
    public int TankSize { get; set; }
}
```

How do i get the the list "PropaneMaint" to work with knockout binding? I need to add/remove from the list like the examples on knockouts site. My viewmodel is defined as below but it's not working.

```
 function propaneMaintViewModel() {
    var viewModel = this;

    viewModel.PropaneMaint = ko.observableArray([]);
    viewModel.addNew = function () {
        viewModel.PropaneMaint.push(
            {
                StoreNumber: 0,
                Tanks: 0,
                TankSize: 0
            }
       );
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new propaneMaintViewModel());
```

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of `propaneMaintViewModel` somewhere? Calling `ko.applyBindings(propaneMaintViewModel());` looks wrong. You should either construct a `propaneMaintViewModel` elsewhere and use it in `ko.applyBindings` or call `ko.applyBindings(new propaneMaintViewModel());`.

Comment: I am not but i agree on just adding the "new" for the parameter. In regards to the page markup, im simply doing a razor for each loop with some buttons. I seen a knockout foreach example but it didn't work with a list that was getting populated from the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout doesn't have a direct binding to any c# model.  What you can do is serialize your MVC viewmodel to a json object, then bind it.  IE:

```
function bindModels(arr) {
    var propaneMaintAssignments = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        propaneMaintAssignments.push(new PropaneMaintAssignment(arr[i]));
    return propaneMaintAssignments;
}

function PropaneMaintAssignment(model) {
    for(var property in model)
       this[property] = model[property];  //bind all properties
}

var json = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.PropaneMaint)); //results in an array
var list = bindModel(json);  //makes an array of named objects
viewModel.PropaneMaint(list);  //adds that array of named objects to your observableArray
```

Comment: hmmm interesting and it makes sense with the comments explaining each step..i do however wonder why the knockout examples use a data-bind="foreach: list"? What context does that apply to and why would it not work here?

Comment: I just noticed you're using KnockoutMVC; I'm not totally familiar with that library, since I just use the base knockout.js and mvc.  The foreach binding does something for each value in an array.  This fiddle shows an example: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/19585/  list in that example should just be the viewmodel property name to iterate.

Comment: Correct, i was able to get it working finally. I used a slightly different approach that bound only the list property of my model versus the entire model. Thanks :D